# Integrated Facebook SDK and Google Maps SDK both return error: 107 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-maps, sdk

[image]I have integrated **Facebook SDK** and **Google Maps SDK** both from pods its given error:

> Showing All Messages
>   ld: 107 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I have try to resolve this problem with no success with these attempts

1. Remove`-ObjC` in other linker flag with no success.
2. Integrate `$(inhereted)`. Still gives error.
3. IRemoved all derived data with no success.

But whenever I remove one of the SDK's (Facebook/Google Maps), its starts working fine. what is the problem?

Any suggestions, if you have better answer how to handle this both SDK in one project.

Comment: can you show ur pod file

Comment: please see this i have attached image of my pods file

Comment: see this creation for podfile https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html and https://github.com/xing/XNGAPIClient/blob/master/Example/Podfile

Comment: Is this project Swift or Objective-c?

Comment: @antony Raphel objective c

Comment: Try cleaning the build folder using **alt, cmd, shift + k**.